# Setting a particular value in Select Tag generated using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am having 3 drop downs side by side for day , month and year. Next to that is an input tag which will have some date in the format "DD-MM-YYYY". What i want to implement is a swap functionality in which on click of the button the date from the input tag should be  set into the 3 select tags and vice versa. For me the date from the drop down is read properly and is set in the text box, but the date from the text box does not get selected the drop down even though it gets assigned to the dropdown models.

My HTML looks like this

```
 <select class="day" name="bday" ng-model="user.bday" age-validate ng-options="day for day in getNumber(1,31,1)"><option value="">DD</option></select>
 <select class="month" name="bmonth" age-validate ng-model="user.bmonth" ng-options="day for day in getNumber(1,12,1)"><option value="">MM</option></select>
 <select class="year" name="byear" age-validate ng-model="user.byear" ng-options="day for day in getNumber(2014,100,-1)"><option value="">YYYY</option></select>
 <input ng-model="social.bdob" readonly="" type="text" /> 
 <span class="toggle" ng-click="swapDOB('bday','bmonth','byear','bdob')"></span>
```

Controller Code is -

```
    $scope.getNumber = function (start, range, order) { // ascending order = 1, descending order = -1
        var arr = new Array(range);
        for (var i = start, j = 0; range--; i = i + order)
            arr[j++] = i;
            return arr;
    }

    $scope.swapDOB = function (pDay, pMonth, pYear, pDob) {
        var temp = $scope.social[pDob];
        $scope.social[pDob] = $scope.user[pDay] + "-" + $scope.user[pMonth] + "-" + $scope.user[pYear]
    //The below logic needs to be changed to some how select the option tag and display the assigned value
        $scope.user[pDay]= temp.split("-")[0];
        $scope.user[pMonth] = temp.split("-")[1];
        $scope.user[pYear] = temp.split("-")[2];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to pass strings in `swap()`. That is the change I will suggest to your HTML

```
<span class="toggle" ng-click="swapDOB()"></span>
```

I suppose you have a way of differentiating when to set the select inputs or the text box in your implementation because at some point, one of the inputs may be undefined (or NaN).

To set the model for the text input from select inputs, you could use

```
$scope.social.blob = $scope.user.bday + "-" + $scope.user.bmonth + "-" + $scope.user.byear;
```

And to set the select inputs from text input

```
var temp = $scope.social.blob.split("-");
$scope.user.bday= parseInt(temp[0]);
$scope.user.bmonth = parseInt(temp[1]);
$scope.user.byear = parseInt(temp[2]);
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5k5CY/1/) to demonstrate these.

Comment: Updating the model is actually not updating the view. Even in your JS fiddle, try filling both the fields and try to swap. Only data from dropdown is swapped to input tag but not vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the HTML correction, i will remove the parameters

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you wanted to set both values at once. I have updated the fiddle (i.e. removed conditions).

Comment: Yeah this is right, so the mistake i was doing was not using parseInt

Comment: That should be the mistake. Splitting the string gives an array of strings that need to be cast to int.